# Intricate exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

This is the question:
$$
\frac{(2^{3n+4})(8^{2n})(4^{n+1})}{(2^{n+5})(4^{8+n})} = 2
$$
I've tried several times but I can't get the answer by working out.I know $n =2$, can someone please give me some guidance? Usually I turn all the bases to 2, and then work with the powers, but I probaby make the same mistake every time, unfortunately I don't know what that is. Thank you in advance.

*EDIT*

This is what I simplified it to in the beginning of every attempt.

$$
\frac{(2^{3n} *16)(2^{6n})(2^{2n}*4)}{(2^{n}*32)(2^{n}*2^{16})} = 2
$$

Therefore

$$
\frac{64(2^{3n+6n+2n})}{(2^{16}*32)(2^{2n})} = 2
$$

 I simplified further:
$$
\frac{2^{11n}}{32768(2^{2n})} =2
$$

$$
2^{11n} = (2^{2n+1})*32768 \\
$$
$$
\frac{2^{11n}}{2^{2n+1}} = 32768
$$

$$
\frac{2^{11n}}{2*2^{2n}} = 32768
$$

And this is the furthest I get, what do i do now?

Comment: If you show us what you do, we'll show you the mistake.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I just did, thank you in advance!

Comment: $4^{8+n}\ne2^n2^{16}$.

Comment: I didn't even realize! Thank you, makes much more sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
\frac{(2^{3n+4})(8^{2n})(4^{n+1})}{(2^{n+5})(4^{8+n})} &= \frac{(2^{3n+4})(2^{3})^{2n}(2^2)^{n+1}}{(2^{n+5})(2^2)^{8+n}} \\
&=\frac{2^{3n+4+6n+2n+2}}{2^{n+5+16+2n}} \\
&=\frac{2^{11n+6}}{2^{3n+21}} \\
&=2^{(11n+6)-(3n+21)} \\
&=2^{8n-15}
\end{align}

Also from the original problem,
\begin{align}
\frac{(2^{3n+4})(8^{2n})(4^{n+1})}{(2^{n+5})(4^{8+n})} &= 2
\end{align}

Therefore,
\begin{align}
2^{8n-15} &= 2^1
\end{align}

Drop the base $2$ on both sides, and we will get
\begin{align}
8n-15 = 1
\end{align}
Thus, $n=2$.

Comment: That's much simpler than what I tried to do! Thank you! Much appreciated :)

Comment: No problem! :-D

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use $$a^{mn}=(a^m)^n$$  and $$a^m\cdot a^n=a^{m+n}\text{ and }\frac{a^m}{a^n}=a^{m-n}$$

For example, $\displaystyle4^{8+n}=(2^2)^{(8+n)}=2^{2(8+n)}$

Finally $a^x=a^y\implies x=y$ if real $a\ne\pm1$

**Reference** : [Exponent Combination Laws](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws)

Comment: Also, notice that 4 and 8 are both powers of 2.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, that's the basis, else things will be really complex

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{2^{11n}}{2*2^{2n}} = 32768
$$

*And this is the furthest I get, what do I do now?*

Multiply both sides by 2. Then you get 
$$
\frac{2^{11n}}{2^{2n}} = 65536.
$$
$$\implies 2^{11n-2n}=2^{9n}=65536.$$
$$\therefore n=\frac{log_2(65536)}{9}=\frac{16}{9}.$$

EDIT: This is wrong, and there should be a $3n$ instead of a $2n$ in the denominator to start with, yielding $n=2$ because $4^{8+n}=4^{16+2n}$, not $4^{16+n}$ as in the question.

Comment: $n = 2$ though, I made a mistake, but I know what it is now, thank you!

Comment: The additions in your comment, Mathster, should be multiplications.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You're right. I deleted my comment.

By the way, by far the easiest way is to start off by taking $log_2$ of both sides.

Then you have $3n+4+3(2n)+2(n+1)-[(n+5)+2(8+n)]=1.$ 

Solving for $n$ to yield the result of $n=2$ is then [even more] trivial.